# $ is not defined in imported js

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a webpage that I have the JavaScript in a separate file from my HTML file. I have imported

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in my HTML file but when I attempt to work in my js file to make some updates after a while away I get the following error

```
ERROR: '$' is not defined.[no-undef]
ERROR: 'document' is not defined. [no-undef]
```

Example where the above errors are references in my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#screenNum").hide(); 

    ...

}
```

The document Renders in the browser with no issues and the JS functions as designed and when I look at the developer tools in the browser there are no errors. I would like to get rid of these errors so that I can focus on actual errors.

It has been a couple years since I have worked on this document and I wanted to make some enhancements to it and am just now getting back to it. I do not recall this error when I last worked in it in Dreamweaver and do not know what I am missing.

All the similar questions I have looked at similar to this seem to deal with when the JavaScript is in the HTML document and not in a separate file.

Comment: `[no-undef]` That sounds like a linting error, not a `ReferenceError`

Comment: Add /* global $, document */ at the top of your JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Tim Hunter, adding the below code worked perfectly.

```
/* global $, document*/
```